# Why function gives #value even though msgbox show right calculated value

Tags: excel, vba, return-value

I am creating a function that calculate the input from an Excel spreadsheet. However, the function is returning `#value!`. When I checked via MsgBox and debug Watch, the function is able to calculate a correct value.

[image: screen shot of Excel sheet]

```
Public Function pT_Flash_PR(comp, zComp, Temp, Pres) As Variant



NC = UBound(comp) - LBound(comp) + 1

Dim VapFrac As Variant
ReDim Tc(1 To NC)
ReDim Pc(1 To NC)
ReDim w(1 To NC)
ReDim Keq(1 To NC)
ReDim xComp(1 To NC)
ReDim yComp(1 To NC)
ReDim acrit(1 To NC)
ReDim bCrit(1 To NC)
ReDim Kappa(1 To NC)
ReDim alpha(1 To NC)
ReDim PR_Kij(1 To NC, 1 To NC)
ReDim psi_Liq(1 To NC)
ReDim psi_Vap(1 To NC)
ReDim phi_Liq(1 To NC)
ReDim phi_Vap(1 To NC)
ReDim Keq_New(1 To NC)
ReDim fug_Liq(1 To NC)
ReDim fug_Vap(1 To NC)


Dim ResSum(1 To 2) As Double

comp = Application.Transpose(comp)
zComp = Application.Transpose(zComp)



    pSat_coeff_Range = Sheets("Database").Range("c3:L18")
    PR_Kij_Database = Sheets("Database").Range("y3:an18")
    
    VapFrac = 0.5
    dVapFrac = 0.001
    RConst = 8.31446261815324



            For j = 1 To NC
                For i = 1 To NC
                
                        rowNum = Application.Match(comp(i), Worksheets("Database").Range("x3:x18"), 0)
                        ColNum = Application.Match(comp(j), Worksheets("Database").Range("y2:AN2"), 0)
                        PR_Kij(i, j) = Application.Index(PR_Kij_Database, rowNum, ColNum)
                        
                        Tc(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(comp(i), pSat_coeff_Range, 8, False) 'Tc in K
                        Pc(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(comp(i), pSat_coeff_Range, 9, False) * 1000
                        w(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(comp(i), pSat_coeff_Range, 10, False)
                                    
                        Keq(i) = Pc(i) / Pres * Exp(5.37 * (1 + w(i)) * (1 - Tc(i) / Temp))
                           
                Next
            Next









For iter02 = 1 To 100

            For iter01 = 1 To 100

                  For j = 1 To 2
                
                      VapFrac = VapFrac + (j - 1) * dVapFrac

                                For i = 1 To NC
                                                                       
                                    Res = zComp(i) * (Keq(i) - 1) / (1 + VapFrac * (Keq(i) - 1))
                                    ResSum(j) = ResSum(j) + Res
                                                                   
                                Next
                    Next

                    dResSum = 1 / dVapFrac * (ResSum(2) - ResSum(1))
                    VapFracNew = VapFrac - ResSum(1) / dResSum
                    
                            Dif = Abs(VapFracNew - VapFrac)
                            If (Dif < 0.00000001) Then
                                Exit For
                            End If

                    VapFrac = VapFracNew
            Next iter01
            
            a_alpha_mixL = 0
            bmixL = 0
            a_alpha_mixV = 0
            bmixV = 0
    
            For i = 1 To NC
                                
                xComp(i) = zComp(i) / (1 + VapFrac * (Keq(i) - 1))
                yComp(i) = zComp(i) * Keq(i) / (1 + VapFrac * (Keq(i) - 1))

                acrit(i) = 0.45724 * RConst ^ 2 * Tc(i) ^ 2 / Pc(i)                                    'ai = 0.45724*R^2*Tci^2/Pci
                bCrit(i) = 0.0778 * RConst * Tc(i) / Pc(i)                                             'bi = 0.07780*R*Tci/Pci
                               
                Kappa(i) = 0.37464 + 1.5422 * w(i) - 0.26992 * w(i) ^ 2                        'Kappai = 0.3796 + 1.5422*wi - 0.2699*wi^2
                alpha(i) = (1 + Kappa(i) * (1 - (Temp / Tc(i)) ^ 0.5)) ^ 2                     'alphai = [1+mi*(1-sqrt(Temp/Tci)]^2
                       
            Next

            For i = 1 To NC
            'Calculation OF a*alpha_mix abd bmix for Liquid
                bmixL = bmixL + xComp(i) * bCrit(i)
                For j = 1 To NC
                    a_alpha_mixL = a_alpha_mixL + xComp(i) * xComp(j) * (acrit(i) * acrit(j) * alpha(i) * alpha(j)) ^ 0.5 * (1 - PR_Kij(i, j))
                Next
    
            'Calculation OF a*alpha_mix abd bmix for Vapour
                bmixV = bmixV + yComp(i) * bCrit(i)
                For j = 1 To NC
                    a_alpha_mixV = a_alpha_mixV + yComp(i) * yComp(j) * (acrit(i) * acrit(j) * alpha(i) * alpha(j)) ^ 0.5 * (1 - PR_Kij(i, j))
                Next
            Next

            'Calculation A AND B constant for Compressibility Equation
            ALPR = a_alpha_mixL * Pres / (RConst * Temp) ^ 2
            BLPR = bmixL * Pres / (RConst * Temp)
                
            AVPR = a_alpha_mixV * Pres / (RConst * Temp) ^ 2
            BVPR = bmixV * Pres / (RConst * Temp)


            'Iteration of Compressibility Equation for Liquid Phase
                ZLiq = 0
                For k = 1 To 100
                    Z = ZLiq
                    ZForm = Z ^ 3 + (BLPR - 1) * Z ^ 2 + Z * (ALPR - 3 * BLPR ^ 2 - 2 * BLPR) - (ALPR * BLPR - BLPR ^ 2 - BLPR ^ 3)
                    
                    dZ = 0.0001
                    Z = ZLiq + dZ
                    ZFormdZ = Z ^ 3 + (BLPR - 1) * Z ^ 2 + Z * (ALPR - 3 * BLPR ^ 2 - 2 * BLPR) - (ALPR * BLPR - BLPR ^ 2 - BLPR ^ 3)
                
                    ZLiq = Z - ZForm / ((ZFormdZ - ZForm) / dZ)
                
                    EpsZLiq = Abs(ZLiq - Z)
                    If (EpsZLiq < 0.0000001) Then
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next

    
            'Iteration of Compressibility Equation for Vapour Phase
                ZVap = 1
                    For k = 1 To 100
                    Z = ZVap
                    ZForm = Z ^ 3 + (BVPR - 1) * Z ^ 2 + Z * (AVPR - 3 * BVPR ^ 2 - 2 * BVPR) - (AVPR * BVPR - BVPR ^ 2 - BVPR ^ 3)
                    
                    dZ = 0.0001
                    Z = ZVap + dZ
                    ZFormdZ = Z ^ 3 + (BVPR - 1) * Z ^ 2 + Z * (AVPR - 3 * BVPR ^ 2 - 2 * BVPR) - (AVPR * BVPR - BVPR ^ 2 - BVPR ^ 3)
                    
                    ZVap = Z - ZForm / ((ZFormdZ - ZForm) / dZ)
                    
                    EpsZVap = Abs(ZVap - Z)
                    If (EpsZVap < 0.0000001) Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next



            'Calculation of Fug Coefficent for Liq and Gas
            EpsK = 0
            For i = 1 To NC
                 ' Calculation of psi Liq for individual compoennt for Fug Coefficient Eq
                psi_Liq(i) = 0
                For j = 1 To NC
                    psi_Liq(i) = psi_Liq(i) + xComp(j) * (acrit(i) * acrit(j) * alpha(i) * alpha(j)) ^ 0.5 * (1 - PR_Kij(i, j))
                Next
                
                ' Calculation of Liquid Fug Coefficient, PhiL for individual component
                phi_Liq(i) = Exp(bCrit(i) * (ZLiq - 1) / bmixL - logE(ZLiq - BLPR) - ALPR / 8 ^ 0.5 / (BLPR) * (2 * psi_Liq(i) / a_alpha_mixL - bCrit(i) / bmixL) * logE((ZLiq + BLPR * (1 + 2 ^ 0.5)) / (ZLiq + BLPR * (1 - 2 ^ 0.5))))
                Cells(i, 17) = PhiL
                        
                ' Calculation of psi Vap for individual compoennt for Fug Coefficient Eq
                psi_Vap(i) = 0
                For j = 1 To NC
                    psi_Vap(i) = psi_Vap(i) + yComp(j) * (acrit(i) * acrit(j) * alpha(i) * alpha(j)) ^ 0.5 * (1 - PR_Kij(i, j))
                Next
    
                
                ' Calculation of Vapour Fug Coefficient, PhiL for individual component
                phi_Vap(i) = Exp(bCrit(i) * (ZVap - 1) / bmixV - logE(ZVap - BVPR) - AVPR / 8 ^ 0.5 / (BVPR) * (2 * psi_Vap(i) / a_alpha_mixV - bCrit(i) / bmixV) * logE((ZVap + BVPR * (1 + 2 ^ 0.5)) / (ZVap + BVPR * (1 - 2 ^ 0.5))))
                Cells(i, 18) = phiV
    
           
            'Calculation of new K values
                Keq_New(i) = phi_Liq(i) / phi_Vap(i)
                
                fug_Liq(i) = xComp(i) * phi_Liq(i)
                fug_Vap(i) = yComp(i) * phi_Vap(i)
            
            'Calculation of summation of difference between new and old K values
                EpsK = EpsK + (xComp(i) * phi_Liq(i) / (yComp(i) * phi_Vap(i)) - 1) ^ 2
    
            Next

                If (EpsK < 0.000000001) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            
            Keq = Keq_New
            
   Next iter02

    pT_Flash_PR = VapFrac
    MsgBox VapFrac

  End Function
```

```
Sub Test()

comp = Range("g33:g35")
zComp = Range("h33:h35")
Temp = Range("h31") + 273.15
Pres = Range("h32")


    VF = pT_Flash_PR(comp, zComp, Temp, Pres)



  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA functions work differently if called from within excel cells. In your case (for example) all your parameters are read as `Variant()` arrays if the function is called from within the VB editor. However, if called from an excel cell they are accepted as `Range`s and you therefore get an error when you do something like `Lbound(someRange)` or `.Transpose(someRange)`. A way around is to check for the caller at the very beginning of your function like this:

```
'Check if called from an excel cell
If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then
  If TypeName(comp) = "Range" Then comp = comp.Value
  If TypeName(zComp) = "Range" Then zComp = zComp.Value
  If TypeName(Temp) = "Range" Then Temp = Temp.Value
  If TypeName(Pres) = "Range" Then Pres = Pres.Value
End If
```

Here I am checking the type of each parameter again to allow for passing literal values.